# Backend instance hours count

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the AppEngine's Backend instances and the daily free quota is 9 instance hours. However, I've been using a Backend with 10 instances for around 16-17 minutes and my usage has already crossed 66%.

The calculation I had in my mind was 17 mins * 10 instances = 170 mins ~ 2.8hrs which is definitely less than 66% of 9 hours.

Can someone explain me the billing scheme here?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess that they count every hour / half hour or something like that, i e 300 minutes = 5 hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests:

> **Instance Hours (billable)** In general, instance usage is billed on an
>   hourly basis based on the instance's uptime. Billing begins when the
>   instance starts and ends fifteen minutes after the instance shuts
>   down. You will be billed only for idle instances up to the number of
>   maximum idle instances set in the Performance Settings tab of the
>   Admin Console. Runtime overhead is counted against the instance
>   memory.

In your case, you'd have 17min of activity + 15min after activity = 32 minutes. So 320 minutes (32 * 10) is pretty close to 2/3 of 9 hours.

You should be able to see the details in the [Usage History](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#viewing) of your application.